# MODULE NOT FOUND after running axios

Tags: reactjs, server, react-router, axios

While I was compiling the code using npm start an error occurred. 
  I create the Axios Instance by running **npm install --save axios** , but after that i run yarn start its not running.**strong text**

```
 Here is the error log: 

         yarn run v1.22.4
   $ node scripts/start.js
   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
     throw err;
     ^

   Error: Cannot find module 'resolve'
   Require stack:
   - /home/falguni/Documents/the_burger_builder/config/webpack.config.js
   - /home/falguni/Documents/the_burger_builder/scripts/start.js
       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/home/falguni/Documents/the_burger_builder/config/webpack.config.js:6:17)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19) {
     code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
     requireStack: [
       '/home/falguni/Documents/the_burger_builder/config/webpack.config.js',
       '/home/falguni/Documents/the_burger_builder/scripts/start.js'
     ]
   }
   error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

```
  This is showing in my terminal and it is not running the server.
```

Comment: please share your webpack.config.js file

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize your folder names and js file names.

Answer (score 0):

try
yarn add axios
instead of 
npm install axios
I am not clear but i think this will work